# TFS server using RDS SQL server connection

Tags: sql-server, tfs, amazon-rds, rds

I am trying to install and configure my TFS Server 2015 and I will like to use a RDS SQL Server but the connection is not working.

[image]

I do not know what am I missing here?

I also check the security groups and create the new security groups and applied to the RDS to allow connection from my TFS server on port 1433.

Any idea?

Comment: Why run your own TFS (IaaS) in the cloud when you can get a PaaS solution from MS? http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Comment: Good point... but I am trying to fix my bugs. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you been able to connect with SQL Studio?

Comment: What does it say when you click "test"?

Comment: The is an timeout connection. It doesn't see the rds. I tested my connection from another instance (centos) and executed a telnet and that worked. Maybe I am doing a wrong configuration or I am missing something else.

Comment: I create a local SQL database but the issue is with the RDS SQL Server. I will like to create that as backend from my data.

Comment: Can you connect to it from SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

TFS only supports Windows Authentication. According to the following page, Amazon RDS for SQL Server now supports Windows Authentication, you may try to set up Windows Authentication for SQL Server DB Instances:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_SQLServerWinAuth.html